# How to interpret the niche overlap index (sensu Piyanka, Gotelli) 1-tail and 2-tail 95% CI?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, ecology, one-tailed-test, two-tailed-test

I am trying to make sure I understand how to interpret Piyanga's niche overlap index and it's simulations in EcoSimR

In short, if index is 0 (no overlap) and 1(complete overlap). I calculated temporal overlap for 3 sites (independently). Here are the results of the simulations following [EcoSimR example](https://www.uvm.edu/%7Engotelli/EcoSim/Niche%20Overlap%20Tutorial.html)

The niche overlap here generates a standard histogram of simulated metric values (blue bars) based on the selected algorithm and metric (Piyanka, RA3). The vertical red line indicates the observed metric for the original data, the pair of vertical long-dash lines indicate the 95% one-tailed cutpoints, and the short-dash lines indicate the 95% two-tailed cutpoints. The latter would constitute a proper 95% confidence interval for the null distribution. Note that these intervals are not based on a normal or other parametric distribution. Instead, they are always estimated directly from the histogram, which means they could be asymmetric, and will be sensitive to the number of replicates used.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Here is my interpretation

1. The observed mean is close to the simulated mean. There is niche overlap i.e. falls between the 2-tail 95%  CI
2. The observed mean is far more than the expected mean. There is significantly greater niche overlap than expected by chance alone i.e. falls outside the 1 and 2-tail 95%  CI
3. The observed mean is more than the expected mean. What can I conclude about its significance since it lies greater than the 2-tail 95% CI but less than the 1 tail. My understanding is that here the 2-tail what I need since I am trying to understand if niche overlap is significantly greater than expected by chance (right) or less expected by chance (left end of tail). Not sure why someone would use the 1-tail test in this case.

My basic questions are (a) is my interpretation correct for (1) and (2). What more can I learn about (3)